# Page doesn't respond while creating a sudoku

Tags: javascript, sudoku

I'm trying to create a correct sudoku.

I created 3 Methods to check the numbers and one to generate the sudoku.

`createSudoku()` tries to create a sudoku.

`colContainsNumber()`: check if the col contains the random number I generated

`rowContainsNumber()`: Same as colContainsNumber, just for the row

`squareContainsNumber()`: Check if a block contains the random number.

In `createSudoku()` I generate the random number, and with a while-loop I keep generate a new number until none of the "contain-Methods" return true (true for "yes the number is already in the row etc.)

Using all methods themselves to create a sudoku works. (For example if I only use rowContainsNumber I'll get a sudoku where no row contains the same number etc.)

But if I use all three Methods together the page won't respond.

I tried to change the order of the methods that I call in the while-loop, but not really much more because the methods are working fine if I only call one of them.

```
function createSudoku() {
    var sudoku = [
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]
    ];
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        for (var j = 0; j < 9; j++) {
            //generate a random number between 1 and 9
            var randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);

            /*Keep generate a random number, until the square doesn't contain 
            the number. This is the loop where I'm supposed to use all three 
            Methods (colContains-, rowContains- and squareContainsNumber) but 
            the page doesn't respond if I use all three of them. If I only use 
            one like you can see now, the generation works fine*/

            while (squareContainsNumber(sudoku, i, j, randomNumber)) {
                randomNumber = Math.floor((Math.random() * 9) + 1);

            }
            sudoku[i][j] = randomNumber;
            solvedSudoku[i][j] = randomNumber;
        }
    }
    return sudoku;
}

function rowContainsNumber(sudoku, col, number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (sudoku[col][i] == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function colContainsNumber(sudoku, row, number) {
    for (var i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
        if (sudoku[i][row] == number) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}

function squareContainsNumber(sudoku, col, row, number)
{
    var minRow, maxRow, minCol, maxCol = 0;
    //Check which column the loop is in, then set the min and max column so I 
    //can get the range of the block
    switch (col) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            minCol = 0;
            maxCol = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            minCol = 3;
            maxCol = 5;
            break;
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            minCol = 6;
            maxCol = 8;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }
    //Check which row the loop is in, then set the min and max row so I 
    //can get the range of the block
    switch (row) {
        case 0:
        case 1:
        case 2:
            minRow = 0;
            maxRow = 2;
            break;
        case 3:
        case 4:
        case 5:
            minRow = 3;
            maxRow = 5;
            break;
        case 6:
        case 7:
        case 8:
            minRow = 6;
            maxRow = 8;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

   //loop through the square and check If the square contains the random number
    for (var i = minRow; i <= maxRow; i++) {
        for (var j = minCol; j <= maxCol; j++) {
            if (sudoku[i][j] == number)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Expected Result would be a correct sudoku where no row, no column and no square contains the same number.

But like I already said, the page just doesn't respond, probably because the while-loop takes too long.

Comment: I suspect that backtracking may be needed to avoid generating an invalid sudoku that, because of cells already assigned a value, can't be fixed by changing the value of the next empty square. Have you looked into existing algorithms to generate a (solved) sudoku board?

Comment: @traktor53 I tried to find some backtracing algorithm, but a lot of them are working with a "sudoku board" that already have values, which mine doesn't have.

Answer (score 0):

The algorithm to randomly select a sudoku cell value based on  fulfilling constraints of not duplicating an existing digit in a row, column or box is incomplete. One may follow the constraints but still find that an empty cell has previously had all of the digits 1-9 allocated as neighbors in a row, cell, or box.

When the posted code reaches this condition it tries to generate a new random digit for the puzzle without checking if it is possible. Since it is not possible the page hangs as it continues to try another random digit that won't work.

This code snippet checks that the houses (row, column or box) of an empty cell actually have an unused digit, and retries the puzzle if not:

```js
var attempts = 0;

function puzzle( sudoku) {
    ++attempts;

    function House() {
        this.index = Object.create(null);
    }
    House.prototype.add = function( n) {
            if( this.index[n]) {
                return 0;
            }
            this.index[n] = true;
            return n;
        };
    
    let houses = [];
    for( var i = 0; i < 27; ++i) {
        houses [i] = new House();
    }
    let rowOf = index =>  Math.floor(index/9);
    let colOf = index =>  index%9;
    let boxOf = index =>  3 * Math.floor( rowOf( index)/3) + Math.floor( colOf( index)/3);
    
    function randomDigit( index) {
        let rowHouse = houses[ rowOf( index)];
        let colHouse = houses[ 9 + colOf(index)];
        let boxHouse = houses[ 18 + boxOf(index)];
        let domain = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].reduce( function( array, digit) {
            if( !(rowHouse.index[ digit] || colHouse.index[digit] || boxHouse.index[ digit])) {
                array.push( digit);
            }
            return array;
        }, []);
        let digit = domain.length ? domain[ Math.floor( domain.length * Math.random())] : 0;
        if( digit) {
            rowHouse.add(digit);
            colHouse.add(digit);
            boxHouse.add(digit);
        }
        return digit;
    }

    var sudoku = [];
    for( var index = 0 ; index < 81; ++index) {
        let digit = randomDigit( index);
        if( digit == 0) {
            break;
        }
        sudoku[ index] = digit;
    }

    if( sudoku.length == 81) {
        return sudoku;
    }
    return puzzle();
}

const sudoku = puzzle();

console.log( "Attempts = " + attempts);
if( sudoku.length < 81) {
    sudoku.push('x');
    console.log("invalid sudoku");
}
for( let i = 0; i < 81; i += 9) {
    console.log( sudoku.slice( i, i+9).toString());
}
```

Running the snippet shows that a large number of attempts may be needed to get a result.

A quick look on the web suggests that this may be an unusual method of generating a completed puzzle and without further experience I am not in a position to comment on its usefulness.